# Restructure a table with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As I can't modify the code itself that generates a table, I'm trying to restructure it in the dom with the help of JQuery. More precisely, I'm trying to move **td id="td03"** out and above **tr id="tr01"**.

```
<table id="myTableID">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tr01">
      <td>2</td>
      <td id="td03">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

All I seem to do is move it about in the tr instead of moving it above the tr

```
$('#tr01').prepend($('#td03').contents());
```

[Fiddle with it](https://jsfiddle.net/TheHiddenSoul/1as8xv4x/).

The expected result would be

```
<table id="myTableID">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="td03">
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr01">
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not valid html

Comment: Show expected results

Comment: expected result added. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are putting text directly inside `<tr>` ...that is still not valid. Nothing can go in `<tr>` other than `<td>` or `<th>`.

Comment: You are right. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is insert before:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#td03").insertBefore($("#tr01"))
})
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbahge9d/3/) of your answer

However, this yields invalid HTML.  The recommendation is that your end result generate property formatted HTML that browsers will render properly.

If you append another table row before tr01 it would give you proper html.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tr01").parent().append("<tr id='tr00'>");
  $("#tr00").append($("#td03"));

})
```

This is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbahge9d/4/) of that working

Comment: can't make a `<td>` a child of `<tbody>`. You might see it work but it's invalid html and any browser could kick it out

Comment: I agree.  I was just following the request of the question submitter.

Comment: then suggest putting another row in perhaps. Just because they ask for it doesn't mean it's right

Comment: I understand. So would it be possible to use jquery to add a <tr> above then place the <td> ?

Comment: That is working wonderfully. Thank you but just one correction for my purpose, it would be :

`$("#tr01").parent().prepend("<tr id='tr00'>");` - Thank you both your kindness !